# Non-yielding IOCP Listener

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Does anyone know what "Non-yielding IOCP Listener" indicates?

On of our SQL Servers just had a bugcheck dump:

```
=====================================================================                                            
       BugCheck Dump                                                                                             
=====================================================================                                            

This file is generated by Microsoft SQL Server                                                                   
version 9.00.5292.00                                                                                             
upon detection of fatal unexpected error. Please return this file,                                               
the query or program that produced the bugcheck, the database and                                                
the error log, and any other pertinent information with a Service Request.                                       


Computer type is AT/AT COMPATIBLE.                                                                               
Bios Version is DELL   - 1                                                                                       
Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 1.5.2                                                                         
Current time is 23:01:04 09/07/12.                                                                               
48 Unknown CPU 9., 2 Mhz processor (s).                                                                          
Windows NT 6.1 Build 7601 CSD Service Pack 1.                                                                    

Memory                               
MemoryLoad = 81%                     
Total Physical = 524278 MB           
Available Physical = 97549 MB        
Total Page File = 524276 MB          
Available Page File = 94472 MB       
Total Virtual = 8388607 MB           
Available Virtual = 7846765 MB       
**Dump thread - spid = 0, PSS = 0x0000000000000000, EC = 0x0000000000000000                                      
***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0008.txt              
* *******************************************************************************                                
*                                                                                                                
* BEGIN STACK DUMP:                                                                                              
*   09/07/12 23:01:04 spid 0                                                                                     
*                                                                                                                
* Non-yielding IOCP Listener                                                                                     
*                                                                                                                
* *******************************************************************************             </pre>                   


SQLDump0008.log contains:

<pre>
 No user action is required.
2012-09-07 18:30:11.28 spid782     Recovery of any in-doubt distributed transactions involving Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has completed. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2012-09-07 20:58:54.53 spid196     The alert for 'average delay' has been raised. The current value of '509' surpasses the threshold '100'.
2012-09-07 20:59:24.74 spid477     The alert for 'average delay' has been raised. The current value of '299' surpasses the threshold '100'.
2012-09-07 21:44:06.53 spid23s     Database mirroring is inactive for database 'ToDoLists'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2012-09-07 21:44:06.59 spid456     The alert for 'average delay' has been raised. The current value of '518' surpasses the threshold '100'.
2012-09-07 21:44:57.98 spid425     Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State: 27.
2012-09-07 21:44:57.98 spid425     The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 425, which had been reset for connection pooling. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
2012-09-07 21:44:57.98 spid808     Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State: 27.
2012-09-07 21:44:57.98 spid808     The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 808, which had been reset for connection pooling. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
2012-09-07 21:44:58.01 spid155     Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State: 27.
2012-09-07 21:44:58.01 spid155     The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 155, which had been reset for connection pooling. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
2012-09-07 21:44:58.03 spid486     Task (Worker 0x00000001B93B21C0) was forced to yield 2 times: 
2012-09-07 21:44:58.04 spid65s     Database mirroring is inactive for database 'Tracking'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2012-09-07 21:44:58.06 spid486     Task (Worker 0x0000000CB9B341C0) was forced to yield 8 times: 
2012-09-07 21:44:58.09 spid486     Task (Worker 0x0000000655A9E1C0) was forced to yield 3 times: 
2012-09-07 21:44:58.10 spid486     Task (Worker 0x00000006C03BE1C0) was forced to yield 8 times: 
2012-09-07 21:44:58.11 spid65s     Error: 1404, Severity: 16, State: 6.
2012-09-07 21:44:58.11 spid65s     The command failed because the database mirror is busy. Reissue the command later.
2012-09-07 21:44:58.11 spid486     Task (Worker 0x0000000C819D01C0) was forced to yield 2 times: 
2012-09-07 21:44:58.49 spid140     The alert for 'average delay' has been raised. The current value of '191' surpasses the threshold '100'.
2012-09-07 21:45:00.66 spid46s     SQL Server has encountered 6 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'Object Plans' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to some database maintenance or reconfigure operations.
2012-09-07 21:45:17.25 spid83s     SQL Server has encountered 6 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'SQL Plans' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to some database maintenance or reconfigure operations.
2012-09-07 21:45:17.25 spid54s     SQL Server has encountered 6 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'Bound Trees' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to some database maintenance or reconfigure operations.
2012-09-07 21:45:17.28 spid45s     The mirrored database "Tracking" is changing roles from "PRINCIPAL" to "MIRROR" due to Role Syncronization.
2012-09-07 21:45:17.61 spid46s     Bypassing recovery for database 'Tracking' because it is marked as a mirror database, which cannot be recovered. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2012-09-07 21:45:29.21 spid45s     Database mirroring is active with database 'Tracking' as the mirror copy. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2012-09-07 21:50:56.94 spid196s    SQL Server has encountered 5 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'Object Plans' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to some database maintenance or reconfigure operations.
2012-09-07 21:50:57.14 spid196s    SQL Server has encountered 5 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'SQL Plans' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to some database maintenance or reconfigure operations.
2012-09-07 21:50:57.14 spid196s    SQL Server has encountered 5 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'Bound Trees' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to some database maintenance or reconfigure operations.
2012-09-07 23:00:09.42 spid438     Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State: 27.
2012-09-07 23:00:09.42 spid438     The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 438, which had been reset for connection pooling. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
2012-09-07 23:01:04.26 Server      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      **Dump thread - spid = 0, PSS = 0x0000000000000000, EC = 0x0000000000000000
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0008.txt
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      *
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      *   09/07/12 23:01:04 spid 0
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      *
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      * Non-yielding IOCP Listener
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      *
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-09-07 23:01:04.29 Server      * Short Stack Dump
2012-09-07 23:01:04.33 spid73      The alert for 'average delay' has been raised. The current value of '304' surpasses the threshold '100'.
2012-09-07 23:01:04.34 Server      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x00000000000002E8
```

The alert for 'average delay' message relates to database mirroring and is an alert [raised](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337446%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) when the time taken to commit transactions goes above the specified time. The `is_event_logged` column is 0 for the 'average delay' alert.

You can see the output from `sys.configurations` at [What can cause a mirroring session to timeout then failover?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22402/what-can-cause-a-mirroring-session-to-timeout-then-failover-sql-server-2005).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IOCP is an I/O Completion Port.  A Non-Yielding IOCP Listener means that the thread that handles the IO completion routines took a (relatively) looooong time doing something, and SQLOS though that it may be stuck/hung/whatever.

Sql server does lots of ASYNC IO.  The way it works is when it submits the IO request to the OS, it says "Do this IO asynchronously. Here's a function pointer to call when it's done."

The function that gets called is the IO completion listener.

Consider a page read from disk.  A thread running a select needs to read a page that's not in memory.  It takes a PAGEIOLATCH, issues the async IO to windows to read the page, and goes to sleep.

When the OS finishes the IO, it calls the IOCP function which flags the IO as "done".  Shortly afterwards, a sql thread finishes its 4ms quantum, and checks for IO's to handle. It flags it as done and signals the issuing thread to wake up.  The SELECT thread get scheduled, releases the PAGEIOLATCH, and life is good.

Now, the amount of work that the IOCP does varies depending on the type of IO involved.  I believe that with DB Mirroring, it does more work than it would if it was just reading a page into the buffer pool.

If you're a programmer working on sql server, and you want to optimize the DB Mirroring code, you might be tempted to put more work in the IOCP mirroring code path vs the SQLOS system thread code path.

Or maybe the IOCP needs to copy the data into some mirroring buffer that is a fixed size, and it sits in a loop until it's done.

Or maybe <> happens, and the IOCP function seems "stuck".

I wouldn't worry about this if it happened during a failover and a lot of LOG activity happened.  If it happens consistently, then it may require further investigation.